# Best way to associate data with a dynamically generated subclass

Tags: objective-c

This code must be able to run on iOS 6.1 and later.

I have a base class which is subclassed dynamically at runtime using objc_allocateClassPair. The base class contains pretty much all the logic (in class methods and instance methods), the subclass should only provide some information, which should be easily available in the superclass methods, which is used to implement the logic. This piece of data is passed as an argument to a class-level factory method of the base class, which generates a new subclass with the data incorporated. So, somehow I need to associate a piece of data with this generated subclass, and I don't know how exactly to do it. I have a few ideas:

- add a class field to the generated class - I'm not sure Obj-C supports this, there is class_getClassVariable but I don't see an option to actually set it - should I set an iVar on the metaclass of the generated subclass?
- associate this data with the generated class object using the objc_setAssociatedObject, which is then available in the superclass methods via objc_getAssociatedObject - this would have the effect that I would have to use the ugly runtime method call to get the data whenever I need it, and I would prefer to use standard syntax (this is also an issue with the class field, because even if Obj-C runtime supports class fields, the syntax does not, I think; but if there is no other way, that's Ok)
- add a class method which returns the data; I would implement a dummy method in the superclass which does nothing / throws an exception and once the subclass is generated, I would set the implementation of this method with method_setImplementation; here I have a problem as the data I need to associate would have to be passed as an argument to this new implementation at the time the implementation is set; basically, I would need to create a function which takes id self and SEL _cmd as arguments and returns my data; I have no idea how to do this in Obj-C, in other languages I could for example use currying:

  ```
  MyData* getMyData(MyData* myData, id self, SEL _cmd) {
      return myData;
  }

  ...

  IMP createImp(MyData *myDataInstance) {
      return curry(getMyData, myDataInstance);
  }
  ```

  and then use the return value of createImp as the second argument to method_setImplementation, basically creating a class-level getter - the problem is I have no idea how to do this in Objective-C, let alone if this is a good idea

So, what would be the best way to code what I'm trying to achieve?

**EDIT**:

As a response to the comment about the use case:
The base class has methods like conformsToProtocol, respondsToSelector and instancesRespondToSelector  (class method) etc. which need to use a protocol type (the data that I'm trying to associate). In order to implement such protocol methods, subclasses of the base class are generated at runtime and made to conform to a protocol that is passed as an argument to the factory method - pseudocode:

```
    + (instancetype)implementorFor:(Protocol *)protocol {
        1. generate unique class name
        2. check if generatedClass for the protocol already exists, use it if it does
        3. if generatedClass doesn't exist - allocateClassPair
          4. addProtocol(generatedClass, protocol)
          5. registerClassPair(generatedClass)
        6. return [[generatedClass alloc] initInstance]
    }
```

The protocol methods are implemented using forwardInvocation and the family (I'm not allowed to give too many details here) - it all works like a charm, but until now, I didn't support the instancesRespondToSelector method (and other custom class level methods) as the implemented protocol type was an instance variable set when in the initInstance method, not a class variable - things changed, and now I need the generated class to know what protocol it conforms to. And this is the reason of the problem - how to have the class know its protocol.
So, this is an already working proprietary application and whereas I would love to learn a better way to do this (i.e. generically implement certain protocol types), it is too late (unless it is something ingenious, then I won't go to sleep until I replace the current solution with a better one). And even if this use case is considered dubious, I would still like to know how one would associate data with a class (i.e. create a class field). After reading a bit after posting this question, associated objects seem to be the way to go.

Comment: The whole idea sounds dubious, and in all likelihood there's a much more straightforward solution. If you can share something about the problem you're trying to solve, that would help.

Comment: I've just edited the question with information about the use case, hope it helps.

Comment: I thought you were already storing the protocol in the target class. Does the class actually adopt the protocol, or are you saying that the protocol is simply stored as a property (and if that's the case, why not adopt the protocol instead)?

Comment: You mean I'm storing it by doing class_addProtocol? If yes - the base class already implements a few other internal protocols, but in the methods I am describing, I am only interested in the particular one passed as argument to the factory method (the respondsToSelector etc. methods check the 'dynamic' protocol only if the superclass methods return NO). So, I still want to know the protocol that was the reason the dynamic subclass was generated. Or do you means something different?

Comment: So couldn't you have the custom protocol adopt a protocol (e.g., `Implementor` or something) you can use to identify it as the protocol of interest?

Comment: That's a good idea - like a 'marker' protocol. But it won't work - we have no idea what protocols that will be because they come from dynamically loaded modules etc. Also, creating another protocol and make all customers / extension providers implement it or it won't work pretty limiting, I would honestly prefer to just be able to do all the mundane stuff internally.